# Maven: Viewing compile options?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to track down this compile error:

```
$ mvn compile
...
[ERROR] /.../Reader.java:[14,13] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
(use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
```

How can find the `-source 1.5` setting in my Maven compilation?  I'm using a plain vanilla `pom.xml` which (as far as I can tell) isn't setting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a plain vanilla `pom.xml` that you have this issue.

By default, the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/), which is called when compiling the sources, compiles with Java 5, whatever you have set up as `$JAVA_HOME`:

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with.

To use a different compiler version (e.g. Java 8), you can set [the following properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source):

```xml
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

or configure the plugin directly:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Also note that Maven requires a minimal Java version which changes with its version. Required Java version is set to Java 5 since maven 3.1.1 (2013-10), to Java 6 since maven 3.2.5 (2014-12), to Java 7 since maven 3.3.9 (2015-11). Full details here: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html, see the Required Java Version column